# Icons in Careers 2.0 page not showing properly

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Here's the story:

1. Clicked Podcast #47
2. Clicked on this [were hiring](https://stackexchange.com/about/hiring) link
3. Clicked on [Web Developer](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/34229/web-developer-stack-exchange-stack-exchange) link
4. Scrolled down the page to find that cute pony in a StackExchange t-shirt
5. Then I saw this:

[image]

Well, the icons seems not to be showing properly.

Using Firefox 21.0 (current release; not beta or aurora or nightly). OK on Google Chrome.

---

<sup>I really am sorry to those who I've offended in my original revision. I really am.</sup>

Comment: Have I been rude or insulting or something in my original post? Please tell me, honestly.

Comment: Reproduced in FF20.0.1.

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware. Not sure why you're being downvoted really.

Comment: @tombull89 I'm pretty sure it's because of [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/180299/1).

Comment: Not happening in Opera.

Comment: @hjpotter92 It may be because the newer Opera versions are now using webkit, same as with chrome (though, IIRC, chrome had recently forked webkit to develop its own).

Comment: Ah, mine is still Presto. And I think Opera only *announced* usage of webkit but haven't released it yet.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I stand corrected then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a tiny dose of CSS magic was needed - should look better now!

Comment: Wait. Is it just me, or did it just disappear?

Comment: It'll be back in just a few hours - it was actually a trial run for a new feature we're launching today.

Comment: Try now - should be back! :)

Comment: It's great! And the workspace looks very nice. :)

Comment: They are! :) In case you're curious what the new feature is: http://blog.careers.stackoverflow.com/2013/05/17/introducing-careers-2-0-company-pages